# If statement being skipped during execution

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am having a problem with this piece of code. The if statement on line 6 is being ignored during execution. I have stepped through the code at this point and the value of the variable file[position] is "subjects.dat". However, it is skipping over the steps in this and going to the related else statement. Any ideas why??

```
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (markComplete.isChecked()) {
                    String toDelete;
                    String[] files = fileList();
                    if (files[position] == "subjects.dat") { //the error occurs at this line
                        toDelete = files[position + 1];
                        boolean deleted = deleteFile(toDelete);
                        if (deleted) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            // Do nothing
                        }
                    } else {                            
                        toDelete = files[position];                     
                        boolean deleted = deleteFile(toDelete);
                        if (deleted) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            //Do nothing
                        }   
                    }

                }                   
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: because it is evaluated to false as String comparisons are not done this way

Comment: @RyanThames isEquals()??? do you mean equals() ??

Comment: This might be one of the most common java error, along with `if (var = 2)` ;)

Comment: For objects, instead of using ==, use the .equals method

Comment: @PremGenError Yes, haha. Whoops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.equals()` to compare the actual value of two strings - otherwise you're checking if they're the same object.

```
if (files[position].equals("subjects.dat")) { 
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @RohitJain whoops, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Always check String equality using `equals() method`. `==` operator cheks if two refrenece variables point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are objects in java and when you use "==", you compare the references (pointers), which usually are different (usually because for short strings some optimization is made). Long story short, use

```
string.equals(anotherString)
```

instead of

```
string == anotherString
```

Answer (score 0):

String - use .equals(). == will never give you true since the objects are different.

Instead of 
files[position] == "subjects.dat" 
use 
files[position].equals("subjects.dat")